# Is $A = \left( \begin{matrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ diagonalizable if $\lambda$ is the only eigenvector of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

My book states the following lemma:

Suppose that $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of $A \in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F})$. Then, $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A = \left( \begin{matrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{matrix}\right)$

But, isn't $A = \left( \begin{matrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ diagonalizable since it is already a diagonal matrix? Or is it impossible to have such a $2\times 2$ matrix with a single eigenvalue in a single diagonal entry and the other a $0$.

Comment: Did you mean to write "... $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of ... "?

Comment: Yes, the second $A$ is diagonalizable, but $\lambda$ is not the only eigenvalue. $0$ is one too.

Comment: @DavidSouth Maybe it would be better to state that $\lambda\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the matrix $\left( \begin{matrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ has *two* eigenvalues: $\lambda$ and $0$.